# Gap of unemployment

Tags: employment-gaps, fresher

It's already 3 months since I graduated in CSE.

I got placed through campus in a startup, worked as a Software developer trainee for 6 months which was to be converted into Full-time offer in June this year.

However due to bankrupt situation the startup had to shutdown, leaving me with no Job. Since then I've applied to 50+ companies. So far I only got 3 responses from AngelList,that too got rejected because they later realized that I'm a fresher.

I don't understand what's the problem, I started working on Data Structures & Algorithms, solve problems on HackerRank considering my weakness as well as getting my hands dirty on  technologies i.e NodeJS , Angular 8 ,  etc.

**I just wanted to know if it would be disastrous to have such gaps (4-5 months)?**
Will I be considered for interview ? I get all the negative thoughts.

If I don't get a job after a month, I'm planning to join InterviewBit academy which offers 6 months of training with Job Referral, would this decision lead to a problem?

Comment: _"as well as getting my hands dirty on New technologies i.e. NodeJS"_ - I wouldn't consider nodeJS as _new_ technology - it's been out there for more than 10 years (May 2009).. Regarding your gap: 4-5 months are not a big deal and could be explained rationally - keep on applying and don't give up, sometimes it takes a while, especially when you are fresh in the industry. Good luck and keep hitting that 'send mail'-button ;)

Comment: @Praveen Sharma, Node js is **not** now tech :) . Its quite old , i.e. 10 years. :) Secondly did you being **Indian**, can you please apply for big product based companies like Zomato, Swiggy, Directi? If you are better than other fresher then you will get the job. Its that simple! Now make sure you apply for better companies. How good are you cracking DS&Algo interview at product based companies?

Comment: @Pratik I'm putting in effort to improve myself on Algorithms & DS , I haven't applied to all popular startups so far , leaving Zomato (I did but didn't get response , ) However Just to cover up the gap I somehow managed to get a freelancing project , currently doing it for a month and meanwhile apply to several  startups again

Comment: As a general rule gaps of employment of less than a year aren't much of a flag. They may ask about it, just have a good reason. But since you are fresh out of school I really wouldn't worry about it, its expected there will be a period after graduation where you are looking for work. There are a lot of good reasons to not start working right away after graduation. Pretty much anything besides "I was in jail" is good enough for a recent grad.

Comment: Maybe I am overinterpreting, but calling to learn the essential tools of work as 'getting hands dirty' shows you are still in the academic mindset and not in the industries mindset. Id suggest you work on your attitude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> would be disastrous to have such gaps (4-5 months)

Usually, it will not be disastrous. I had a gap of 3 months, and when I started job hunting, I landed a good job in just a few days.

However, just doing nothing while waiting is not a very good choice either. Take any opportunity you have for getting knowledge and experience. The following is a good way to start:

> I'm planning to join InterviewBit academy which offers 6 months of training with Job Referral

Comment: I don't know about InterviewBit but it could be a problem if it is a full time training as the OP might not have time to apply beside. Anyway I know how painful job hunting can be as a fresh graduate (faced that a few months ago...). It takes a lot of time to find the right offer + applying (sometimes require to register on a specific site, to fill out some informations etc) + doing interviews etc. My suggestion is to be strict with yourself: wake up at 8, spend 2 hours finding offers, apply until 1pm, then do some training during the afternoon. It will for sure work out, just be patient.

Comment: @stbr: you are right, a good life discipline is very important, even though not many of us can respect it (I am one of "us"). Exactly what happens in OP's life, only OP knows, so he / she will have to make decisions based on the specific details.